# How to get chartdata from ajax call into javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, charts

I am working with amcharts and i have a file (data.php) that contains some php code used to produce the "var chartdata=[''];" for the chart. It also has the javascript for drawing the chart. It takes 3 variables, user-id, dateStart and dateEnd. 
I have also this second file (view.php) that has a form which submits its data to the file above via $_GET method. In this file i have a space to draw chart right below the form.

What i want to do is for the user to enter user-id, dateStart, dateEnd then submit,, and get the chart shown below the form (in the 'div')  the chart should redraw every time user hits submit. For it i thought using jQuery $.ajax but i can't draw the chart. In the specified div, it brings only the "var chartdata=[' all chart data here '];"

here is the ajax code in view.php:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "data.php",
    data: {user: $("#user").val(), dtStart: $("[name=dtStart]").val(), dtEnd: $("[name=dtEnd]").val()},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {

    $("#chartdiv").html(' '); 
    $("#chartdiv").html(data); 
      }
    });
```

and here is the code for drawing the graph:

```
var chart;
var average = 90.4;
AmCharts.ready(function() {

// SERIAL CHART    
chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/";
chart.autoMarginOffset = 5;
chart.marginTop = 0;
chart.marginRight = 10;    
chart.zoomOutButton = {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    backgroundAlpha: 0.15
};
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.categoryField = "date";

// AXES
// category
var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
categoryAxis.minPeriod = "mm"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
categoryAxis.dashLength = 1;
categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.15;
categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
categoryAxis.equalSpacing = false;

// value                
var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
valueAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
valueAxis.dashLength = 1;
valueAxis.logarithmic = true; // this line makes axis logarithmic
chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

// GUIDE for average
var guide = new AmCharts.Guide();
guide.value = average;
guide.lineColor = "#CC0000";
guide.dashLength = 4;
guide.label = "average";
guide.inside = true;
guide.lineAlpha = 1;
valueAxis.addGuide(guide);


// GRAPH
var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.type = "smoothedLine";
graph.bullet = "round";
graph.bulletColor = "#FFFFFF";
graph.bulletBorderColor = "#00BBCC";
graph.bulletBorderThickness = 1;
graph.bulletSize = 1;
graph.title = "Price";
graph.valueField = "price";
graph.lineThickness = 2;
graph.lineColor = "#00BBCC";
chart.addGraph(graph);

// CURSOR
var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
chartCursor.categoryBalloonDateFormat = "DD MMM, JJ:NN:SS";
chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

// SCROLLBAR
var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

// WRITE
chart.write("chartdiv");
}); 

</script>
```

can you give me some help please? I'm unfamiliar with jQuery and i'm trying my best to figure out how to solve this..
Thanks
Regards

Comment: Could you share your php code here too please.

Comment: <?php
$javascript ="";
//connect to db
//Connection details
$dbhost='nsetf.com';
$dbuser='it';
$dbpass="it";
$conn=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('error connecting to MySQL');
$dbname='it';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
 $dtstart = $_GET["dtStart"]." 00:00:00";
 $dtend = $_GET["dtEnd"]." 21:59:00";
 //".$_GET['user']."
 //$dtstart = "2013-06-01 00:00:00";
 //$dtend = "2013-06-01 23:59:00";

Comment: //$sql = mysql_query("SELECT vehicle_plate, fuel_level, data_ora FROM chart_data WHERE vehicle_plate = 434 AND data_ora > '2013-06-01 00:00:00' AND data_ora < '2013-06-01 23:30:00'");  
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT vehicle_plate, fuel_level, data_ora FROM chart_data WHERE vehicle_plate = ".$_GET['user']." AND data_ora > '".$dtstart."' AND data_ora < '".$dtend."'");
 while($rez = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $timestamp = trtotime($rez['data_ora']);
                  $data_ora = date("Y,m,d,H,i", $timestamp);                   
                  $fuel_level = $rez['fuel_level'];

Comment: if(!empty($javascript)) $javascript=$javascript.",";
           
$javascript=$javascript."{ date: new Date(".$data_ora."), price: ".$fuel_level."}";
 }
$javascript = "var chartData = [".$javascript."];";
 // echo $javascript;
?>

Answer (score 1):

Try this, comment the line:- `AmCharts.ready(function() {` and `});` . This worked for me. Qutoing from this [link](http://www.amcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9398):-

> "AmCharts.ready event makes sense only when charts are initialized on
>   the page itself to make sure that the page is loaded before trying to
>   create the charts."